# Polymorphic call going to base class instead of subclass

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Upon an object of type C calling `MethodX`, I'm expecting the `MethodY()` call in B (highlighted with question marks) to end up calling C's `MethodY`. But a debug session is showing it's calling A's `MethodY()`.

I'm stumped why. A breakpoint in B's `MethodX()` clearly shows `this` is an object of type C. I Have tried `this.MethodY();` as well as removing the virtual/override and using new, with the same results. Am I confused with another language or have I overlooked something?

```
public abstract class A {
  protected virtual void MethodY() {...}   // This one's being called.
}

public class B : A {
  protected override void MethodY() {...}

  public override void MethodX() {
     MethodY();   // ???
  }
}

public class C : B {
  protected override void MethodY() {...}   // But want this one to be called

  protected override void MethodX() {
    base.MethodX();
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm expecting the `MethodY()` call in `B` to end up calling `C`'s `MethodY`

It does

```
public abstract class A
{
    public virtual void MethodX()
      => Console.WriteLine("A - X");

    public virtual void MethodY()
      => Console.WriteLine("A - Y");
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void MethodY()
      => Console.WriteLine("B - Y");

    public override void MethodX()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B - X");
        MethodY();
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public override void MethodY()
      => Console.WriteLine("C - Y");

    public override void MethodX()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C - X");
        base.MethodX();
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var c = new C();
    c.MethodX();
}
```

**Output**

```
C - X
B - X
C - Y
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/LYM9Q7)

Comment: Ok, I'm not going crazy. I'll put some logging in rather than relying on a debugger breakpoint and if still bad, check your demo for differences. Thx.

Comment: Still bad with logging. I haven't had a chance to dig deeper but will mark you answer as correct as you clearly showed the expected behavior.

Comment: I did find out what my issue was - unlike the code I showed above, I hadn't actually defined `B:MethodY()`. I'm still not sure why this is needed as `this` in `B:MethodX()` is of type C and`B:MethodY()` never gets called anyway. Do I just declare an empty `B:MethodY()` to keep the polymorphism chain happy?